# CSS and JavaScript appearing inline in sourcecode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that runs smoothly, but I just saw that when I'm viewing the source, in Chrome and IE9, it shows my css and javascript inline instead of the link to the files. `<style type="text/css" style="display:none">[my css]</style>` instead of the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` that I see in my PHP editor and that I coded on purpose. I don't see things like this on other websites, only at mine.

How is this possible? A certain change in server settings?

Comment: Possible to post a example of whats going wrong so we can see it ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally click on the "Scripts" tab in the developer tools frame?

Comment: @PatrickR The site is www.drawsomethingwords.com and I tried to turn off all developertools, if I am not missing one I've turned it all off and it's still happening. Is there a certain option that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser tools are just in-lining it to make your debugging easier. This is merely a convenience to show you the flow of the page. The files are still external and shared across many pages.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why it's only happening on this site and not on others and in 2 different browsers? I'm certain I don't have browsertools active in IE9.

Comment: @user1269707 it is a tough one as I can't get this to happen on your site in Chrome or IE9. Did you switch from inline to external and perhaps were looking at a cached version from before the change?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different ways of adding CSS to your HTML pages: inline, external, and attribute-based.

**Inline CSS** is what you have now. It's when the CSS code is directly embedded into your HTML.

**External CSS** is when you reference a CSS file, like your second example.

**Attribute based CSS** is when you directly set attributes in the HTML file. Ex:

```
<div style="CSS HERE"></div>
```

All 3 methods work the same, but for abstraction purposes, external stylesheets are recommended.

In your case, the PHP editor is probably injecting the CSS directly into your code.

Comment: And the problem is that I use external stylesheets, but they appear in browsers inline.

Comment: What do you mean by PHP editor? Just a notepad-like editor or a special software to create websites?

Comment: I mean PHPStorm. But when I open them with notepad it's also ok, so appearing like a external link.

Comment: As Sohnee said below, it could just be the developer tools you're using then.